# Selenium PHP fillfield() via xpath

Tags: php, selenium, xpath

The html:

```
<div class="input-container" data-keyid="5"> <label> Keyword </label> <input class="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter text"></input>
```

I am trying to fill a text box which has no id,label,name or value using PHP

```
file_put_contents('p.html', $page->getHtml());
$HTML='p.html';

$pageHtml = file_get_contents($HTML);
if (false === $pageHtml) {
    die("Error: Couldn't load page content");
}

$doc = new DomDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($pageHtml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
```

I would like to do something like below using xpath. It doesn't work but to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
$page->fillField('//input[@class="keyword-input"]', 'keyword');
```

The error is to be expected Fatal error: Uncaught Form field id|name|label|value
as it is only expecting one of those four inputs but not the xpath. I have no idea how to write this.

How could I do a fillfield using xpath and PHP?

Comment: Could you share desire HTML as well..:)

Comment: Please edit your question and share this HTML and also mentioned why doesn't work, is there any exception or anything else??

Answer (score 0):

Check the fillField method and see that it does not work with css, this method uses id|name|label|value attributes, so you need to pass the value of the attribute.

If you need to use xpath you should have have a method find in the page object and use it like:

```
$page->find('xpath', '//input[@class="keyword-input"]')->setValue("keyword");
```

Css alternative:

```
$page->find('css', 'input.keyword-input')->setValue("keyword");
```

For checking checkboxes use find with check(), uncheck() for checkbox and click() for radio box.
Make sure you are using the right selector for check box/radio box it should be input element.

To check the checkbox with the Name, it should be:

```
$page->find('xpath', '//*[@class="checkbox cat_name"]')->check();
```

The check box should be a input element, if is not working then the selector is not ok.

Comment: I am able to fill the text box using find. Below are checkboxes for categories. I am unable to use checkField also due to same reason as for fillField. I tried:

    $page->find('xpath', '//span[@class="checkbox cat_name"]//div[@class="state"]')->setValue("Name");

Eg where the keyword inputed was a name:

    $page->find('xpath', '//input[@class="keyword-input "]')->setValue("Joe Bloggs"); can I check a checkbox using xpath and find?

Comment: you cannot set value to a div as i see in the above code for Name, the element should be an input.

Comment: If below are a list of checkboxes and I wish to check the Name one how may this be done?

html:

<div class="label">

    Name

    <span class="checkbox cat_name">
        <div class="state"></div>
    </span>

Comment: Just a quick note, using xpath such as `//input[@class="keyword-input"]` will fail if there are multiple classes present on the element. This will work if there is only one class on the element, and the class is `keyword-input`. In situations where the element may have more than one class, use `contains()` instead: `//input[contains(@class,"keyword-input")]`